# capture data between difficult pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, string

This is the String i am getting from textfile in python:

```
    String= '''/begin FUNCTION N1ame1 Some texts and special char 
            /begin Variable_1name1  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111 BAd_afd111
            /end Variable_1name1
            /begin Variable_1name2  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222 BAd_afd222
            /end Variable_1name2
            /begin Variable_1name3    
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333 BAd333_afd333 333DSFadss
            /end Variable_1name3
            FUNCTION_DFADS
        /end FUNCTION
        /begin FUNCTION N2ame2 Sometexts and special char "dlfkjaodfja;lkd 
            /begin Variable_1name1  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1 BAd_afd111_1
            /end Variable_1name1
            /begin Variable_1name2  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222_2 BAd_afd222_2
            /end Variable_1name2
            /begin Variable_1name3  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3 BAd333_afd333_3 333DSFadss_3
            /end Variable_1name3
            FUNCTION_DFADS
    /end FUNCTION'''
```

**I need to get the data using single FUNCTION name and multiple VARIABLE names:**

example 1: if /begin FUNCTION N1ame1 and /begin Variable_1name1
expected output:

```
    ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111','BAd_afd111']
```

example 2: if /begin FUNCTION N1ame2 and /begin Variable_1name1 , /begin Variable_1name3
expected output: (two dimensional array output also no issues)

```
    ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1', 'BAd_afd111_1','Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3','BAd333_afd333_3','333DSFadss_3']
```

I tried basic pattern matching,split,findall functions but two line pattern matching is diffcult:

```
    res = re.findall('begin(.*?)end', string, re.DOTALL)

print ( [s.split() for s in re.findall(r'/Variable_1name1\s+((?:.+\n)+?)/end ', String)] )
```

I have solution with for loop trying in regex and understanding concept it is possible with this pattern?

Comment: Again, this is NOT a regular expression problem.  This is simple text parsing.  Do one line at a time.  Split the line by words.  Based on the words, you know what you need.

Comment: Please share what you tried to solve the actual problem. You've spent a lot of effort constructing a long and complicated text example that doesn't really do anything other than making the problem hard to read, but the only code you shared just matches bits of text between `begin` and `end`. What part of the problem are you stuck on? Also, how is input providedl; what does a solution need to look like - a function? What are its parameters? Please show an example of actual code you wrote so far and explain where you're stuck specifically. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is not clear what the end output should be like. If you need it like a nested string list, `[['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111','BAd_afd111'], ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1', 'BAd_afd111_1','Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3','BAd333_afd333_3','333DSFadss_3']]`, then you'd still need two regexps, and the whole efficiency will be low. Use string parsing, it is much better in terms of performance and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Just basic text parsing.

```
String= '''/begin FUNCTION N1ame1 Some texts and special char 
        /begin Variable_1name1  
            Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111 BAd_afd111
        /end Variable_1name1
        /begin Variable_1name2  
            Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222 BAd_afd222
        /end Variable_1name2
        /begin Variable_1name3    
            Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333 BAd333_afd333 333DSFadss
        /end Variable_1name3
        FUNCTION_DFADS
    /end FUNCTION
    /begin FUNCTION N2ame2 Sometexts and special char "dlfkjaodfja;lkd 
        /begin Variable_1name1  
            Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1 BAd_afd111_1
        /end Variable_1name1
        /begin Variable_1name2  
            Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222_2 BAd_afd222_2
        /end Variable_1name2
        /begin Variable_1name3  
            Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3 BAd333_afd333_3 333DSFadss_3
        /end Variable_1name3
        FUNCTION_DFADS
/end FUNCTION'''

data = {}
variable = False
for line in String.splitlines():
    parts = line.split()
    if parts[0] == "/begin":
        if parts[1] == "FUNCTION":
            funcname = parts[2]
            data[funcname] = []
        elif parts[1].startswith('Variable'):
            variable = True
    elif parts[0] == "/end":
        variable = False
    elif variable:
        data[funcname].append(parts)
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{'N1ame1': [['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111', 'BAd_afd111'],
            ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222', 'BAd_afd222'],
            ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333', 'BAd333_afd333', '333DSFadss']],
 'N2ame2': [['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1', 'BAd_afd111_1'],
            ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222_2', 'BAd_afd222_2'],
            ['Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3', 'BAd333_afd333_3', '333DSFadss_3']]}
```

Comment: updated the question i have a solution with for loop trying in regex for less line of code

Comment: Variable name changing is working in this for loop but function name filtering how to do it for only N1ame1 @Tim Roberts

Comment: Do you see that the resulting dictionary is indexed by the function name?  Surely you know how to select an item from a dictionary.

Comment: `elif parts[1].startswith('Variable_1name2'):pprint(data['N2ame2'])` understood

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pprint
import re
from collections import defaultdict

text= '''/begin FUNCTION N1ame1 Some texts and special char 
            /begin Variable_1name1  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111 BAd_afd111
            /end Variable_1name1
            /begin Variable_1name2  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222 BAd_afd222
            /end Variable_1name2
            /begin Variable_1name3    
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333 BAd333_afd333 333DSFadss
            /end Variable_1name3
            FUNCTION_DFADS
        /end FUNCTION
        /begin FUNCTION N2ame2 Sometexts and special char "dlfkjaodfja;lkd 
            /begin Variable_1name1  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1 BAd_afd111_1
            /end Variable_1name1
            /begin Variable_1name2  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222_2 BAd_afd222_2
            /end Variable_1name2
            /begin Variable_1name3  
                Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3 BAd333_afd333_3 333DSFadss_3
            /end Variable_1name3
            FUNCTION_DFADS
    /end FUNCTION'''

# one can find the blocks of needed lines between the begin and end markers with re.findall

lst = re.findall(r'\/begin Variable_(\dname\d\s)(?:\W+)(.*?)\s*\/end Variable_', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

 - (\dname\d\s) - capture the key
 - (?:\W+) - remove extra space
 - (.*?) - capture the value string

# we get the list of tuples that is easily converted into a dictionary.

[('1name1 ', 'Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111 BAd_afd111'), ('1name2 ', 'Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222 BAd_afd222'), ('1name3 ', 'Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333 BAd333_afd333 333DSFadss'), ('1name1 ', 'Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1 BAd_afd111_1'), ('1name2 ', 'Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222_2 BAd_afd222_2'), ('1name3 ', 'Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3 BAd333_afd333_3 333DSFadss_3')]


d = defaultdict(list)

for t in lst:
    d[t[0]].append(t[1:])


pprint.pprint(d)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'1name1 ': [('Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111 BAd_afd111',),
                         ('Adlkfj_dADDF_A32111_1 BAd_afd111_1',)],
             '1name2 ': [('Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222 BAd_afd222',),
                         ('Adlkfj_dADDF_A32222_2 BAd_afd222_2',)],
             '1name3 ': [('Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333 BAd333_afd333 333DSFadss',),
                         ('Adlkfj_dADDF_A32333_3 BAd333_afd333_3 '
                          '333DSFadss_3',)]})
```